# output of 'iptables -L -nv' commands meaning

Tags: unix, iptables

`root@linux #iptables -L -nv`

The output looks like this

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 89658 packets, 116M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 122K   97M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.43.104       0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 70753 packets, 70M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 141K   61M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.43.104
```

what relation between `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 89658 packets, 116M bytes)`
and below that line.
and `Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 70753 packets, 70M bytes)`
and it's below the line.

I get confused what is 70753 packets vs 141K pkts and 70M vs 61M

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you see the global statistic for that chain with default policy ACCEPT, so that mean you have statistic of whole connection, down get the specific statistic of packets matching that rule.

Answer (score 0):

Within an iptables chain, the rules are checked **from top to bottom**. Packets which didn't match the 1st rule will be tested against the 2nd, then against the 3rd, and so on. Built-in chains have a so-called 'policy' which you can imagine as a virtual rule at the very bottom of the chain – if a packet didn't match any custom rules at all, then it'll hit the policy rule at the end.

So for example, the INPUT chain has:

1. a custom ACCEPT rule that matches the source IP address (so far matched 122K packets);
2. a default ACCEPT "policy" rule that matches everything (so far matched 89.6K packets).

(This also means the firewall is *wide open* – even if packets didn't match the custom IP-based rule, they're still being allowed by the policy rule. It was probably supposed to be changed to DROP?)